# I have a list containes tow maps, i would to print the key and the value of map one with dart

Tags: dart

```dart
void main() {
  List users = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "mike", "code": "01"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "jack", "code": "02"}
  ];
}
```

How do I print the id key for example or name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Loop** the `list` to get access to every child `Map`. Then you can print any thing you want.

```dart
void main() {
  var original = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "mike", "code": "01"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "jack", "code": "02"}
  ];
  
  original.forEach((map) {
    print('id: ${map['id']}');
    print('name: ${map['name']}');
  });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots in solutions unless you are also posting it as text. Screenshots makes it harder to use the solution.

Comment: @julemand101 okey, sorry for bad answer, i was update the code